# Does a procedural macro compile in one thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have implemented a procedural macro to generate a method which returns a number:

```
extern crate unique_type_id;
#[macro_use]
extern crate unique_type_id_derive;

#[test]
fn sequential_simple() {
    use unique_type_id::SequentialTypeId;
    #[derive(SequentialTypeId)]
    struct Test1;
    #[derive(SequentialTypeId)]
    struct Test2;

    assert_eq!(Test1::id().0, 0u64);
    assert_eq!(Test2::id().0, 1u64);
}
```

I have this implementation but I don't know whether should I place my static `ID` under a mutex or not:

```
fn inc_id() -> u64 {
    unsafe {
        static mut ID: u64 = 0u64;

        let old_value = ID;
        ID += 1;
        old_value
    }
}

fn sequential_implementor(ast: &syn::DeriveInput) -> quote::Tokens {
    let name = &ast.ident;
    let (impl_generics, ty_generics, where_clause) = ast.generics.split_for_impl();
    let id = inc_id();

    quote! {
        impl #impl_generics unique_type_id::SequentialTypeId for #name #ty_generics #where_clause {
            fn id() -> unique_type_id::TypeId {
                unique_type_id::TypeId(#id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the procedural macro only uses one thread then there is no need for a mutex, but I don't know this.

Comment: Do you really think that the overhead of a `Mutex` or an `Atomic*` is at all going to even be detectable? I'm pretty sure you are focusing on the wrong thing.

Comment: @Shepmaster i just wantedto know is it necessary or not. However, I even doubt that this code can work correctly all the time. It's better to rewrite it to use files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And what happens when you use this in multiple files or even multiple crates? I think the compiler doesn't guarantee anything, and you simply shouldn't use global state at all (it might fork for `proc_macro` calls, run multiple compiler instances, use threads, ...).

To make it thread safe (and to avoid using `unsafe`) you could use `AtomicUsize` like this:

```
fn inc_id() -> usize {
    use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering, ATOMIC_USIZE_INIT};
    static ID: AtomicUsize = ATOMIC_USIZE_INIT;
    ID.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst)
}
```

Comment: I am also afraid of this. So I see the only way is to use a temporary file with locks. I think this will be better.